# Save before req.session.destroy() ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session, express

I want to save the session value "image location" into the database before I have destroyed the session in logout route

The solution adopted by me is :

```
app.get('/logout',function(req,res){

    Person.update({ username: req.session.user_name }, { $set: {lastimage: req.session.userimage[req.session.img_idx]}}, function(error,update)
            {
                if(update){ 
                req.session.destroy(function() {
                     res.end();
                });
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                    res.end();
                }

                }       

            });
});
```

But when I am using this get location route the task is accomplished i.e the value in person db is updated but in return there is some weird error shown

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
    at options.key (/opt/expressjs/app.js:381:94)
    at callbacks (/opt/expressjs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/opt/expressjs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/opt/expressjs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/opt/expressjs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (/opt/expressjs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/opt/expressjs/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at resume (/opt/expressjs/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:65:7)
    at SendStream.error (/opt/expressjs/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:80:37)
    at SendStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

Why is it so. I am using ExpressJs sessions and mongodb

P.S: The line /opt/expressjs/app.js:381:94 is

```
Person.update({ username: req.session.user_name }, { $set: {lastimage: req.session.userimage[req.session.img_idx]}}, function(error,update)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried saving

'req.session.userimage[req.session.img_idx]' in some var before use ?

for example:

```
var uName = req.session.user_name,
    uImage = req.session.userimage[req.session.img_idx];

Person.update({ username: uName }, { $set: {lastimage: uImage }}, function(error,update) { ...
```

BTW, you may be calling res.end() twice, which will make things weird.

**EDIT:**

```
app.get('/logout', function(req,res) {

    var uName  = req.session.user_name,
        uImage = req.session.userimage[req.session.img_idx];

    Person.update({ username: uName }, { $set: {lastimage: uImage }}, function(error,update) {

        if(error)
            console.log(error);

        // This actually destroys the session
        delete req.session;
        res.end();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah I had tried and its also giving some times no error and some times error.
It is the same with the both solution. Some time the response is 200 ok and some times 500 but at both time the task i.e database update is done.

Comment: I think this is the problem with asynchronous behavior not well understood by me.
And the route is first deleting before the database update but if is this problem then why updating the database with right value before the deletion.

Comment: I edited the response with a better solution. Could you please try if it works?

Comment: When I used ...var uName = req.session.user_name,
    uImage = req.session.userimage[req.session.img_idx];
 Person.update({ username: uName }, { $set: {lastimage: uImage}}, function(error,update)
          {
           if(update){ 
       req.session.destroy(function() {
       res.end();
    });
    if(error){
           //console.log(error);
        res.end();
       }
       
       }  
           
          });
It works and uptil now no error is coming thanks.. if problem exists I will choose the second option :)